# How to speed up the magento 2.2.5 website in production mode

Tags: magento2, jquery, optimization, pagespeed, loading

How to speed up the Magento 2.2.5 website in production mode

I have tried all default options but still its very slow

website url : [https://www.thedottedi.in/]

please help me out on this

Thanks in advance .

Comment: That site seems quite fast and responsive at 19.30 UTC. What sort of timings are you aiming at?

Comment: Thanks for comment MR.Dominic Xigen , coming to mobile devices its very slow .
as i feel jquery is blocking site can have look once